# Finding The Function For An Unusual Sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, functions, power-series

**Note. I want a function that can be graphed on desmos, I know wolframalpha, Python, JS, etc.., may work, but I really would like to find a function that will work with a standard graphing calculator, I also don't want to use step functions or approximations, etc... I really would like a 'closed function I can play around with, use parametrically, and so on...., so keep that in mind, thank you!**

I found / came up with a sequence while working on something. The pattern is easy to spot! **Please See My Fig., sorry the string of numbers is so big.**

The pattern is, despite the length of time it takes to write out, pretty simple but I can't seem to find its function. Can anyone help? Thank you all so much!

[image]

Comment: The $n^{th}$ term of the sequence is $\left(\frac12;\frac12\right)_n$ where $(a;q)_n \stackrel{def}{=} \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (1-aq^k)$ is the [q-Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol), see wiki entry for more info about the function.

Comment: @achillehui, thank you! I'm glad to know what I'm working with. Do you know if there is a way to write this so that it can be graphed on desmos / some other graphing calculator??

Comment: On [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/), you can get a plot using the command `ListPlot[Table[QPochhammer[1/2,1/2,n],{n,1,10}]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$a_1=1-\frac12$$ and in general, $$a_n = a_{n-1}-a_{n-1}\left(\frac12\right)^n=a_{n-1}\left(1-2^{-n}\right),$$ so that $$a_n=\left(1-2^{-1}\right)\cdots\left(1-2^{-n}\right)=\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1-2^{-k}\right)$$

For example,
$$a_5=\frac{1\cdot3\cdot7\cdot15\cdot31}{2\cdot4\cdot8\cdot16\cdot32}$$

**EDIT**

Here are some more examples.

$$\begin{align}
a_1&=\frac12=.5\\
a_2&=\frac{1\cdot3}{2\cdot4}=\frac38=.375\\
a_3&=\frac{1\cdot3\cdot7}{2\cdot4\cdot8}=\frac{21}{32}=.328125
\end{align}$$

If this can be simplified any further, I don't see how.

[image]

The points are plotted for $n=1,2,\dots,19$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'd like to accept it. Unfortunately, I'm either missing the meaning of your notation, or what you put isn't yielding the numbers. Could you please expand on the above? Thank you!

Comment: @JinnyEcckle Could you show me a case where you don't get the right number?  I'm not sure what to explain.

Comment: Sure, $$(1-2^{-n})$$

Does not equal 0.375, for n=2

Comment: I may be totally missing the point here, however.

Comment: The simplest way to be done with the question without even explaining would be to write a function purely in terms of n that yields all the numbers.

Comment: The $\prod$ means *product.*  I did give the simplest formula I can find, purely in terms of $n$.  The point of this site is not to give answers without explanation.

Comment: Ok, I see what the issue is. You aren't giving a function for the series, you're showing a way of generating the series through arithmetic.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean, but I'm trying to graph this, and the calculator will not recognize what you put in such a way that it will yield a graph corresponding to my goal.

Comment: I really am thankful for your time. Perhaps I just failed to explain what I want well enough.

Comment: Does this better explain what I mean?
n=1=0.5, 
n=2=0.375,
n=3=0.328125

Comment: @JinnyEcckle I don't think there is a formula suitable for use with a graphing calculator.  This would be easy to do with a spreadsheet like Excel, or with a scripting language  like python.  Is one of those a possibility for you?

Comment: Thank you for putting in all the effort you have. I'm working with desmos, so there's a fair amount of flexibility. However, if need be, I could use those methods. However, I hope a solution can be found as I would prefer it, and think there's likely a way. Once more, Thank you!

Comment: @JinnyEcckle: If you go to [WolframAlpha](https://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Product%5B1-1%2F2%5Ek%2C%7Bk%2C1%2C10%7D%5D) and enter, say, `Product[1-1/2^k,{k,1,10}]`, you'll get a plot of the first ten values. ... As @ achille notes in a comment to your question, the values can be expressed in $q$-Pochammer notation, but that's just sweeping the product notation under the rug; there's (probably) no "closed form" that avoids calculating the product. (This is like with the factorial. "$5!$" is a nice compact symbol, but calculation requires expanding it to "$1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 5$".)

Comment: @JinnyEcckle: On Desmos, you can start typing `y=prod` into an entry field, and you'll get the product notation symbol, $$y=\prod_{n=\square}^{\square}\square$$ Change the bottom to `k=1`, the top to `n`, and the right-hand expression to `1-1/2^k`. Desmos will then plot a "step function" of your values (including $1$ for $n=0$, representing an "empty" product). I don't use Desmos enough to know how to restrict the plot to just the integers.